# Attribute declared in default? (State design pattern)

Tags: c++, class, default, private, encapsulation

I have class `Prince` and `Frog` (both are children of `State` (which is virtual) and have slightly differently declared methods `welcome()` and `sayGoodbye()`

My only question is why isn't `State* m_state` public? (Is it default? -- and what does THAT mean?) Code is 100% good, but I have never seen declaration like this until the teacher gave us materials about Design Patterns.

**Monster.h**

```
class Monster{
    State* m_state;
public:
    Monster();
    void kiss();
    void welcome();
    void sayGoodbye();
    ~Monster();
};
```

**Monster.cpp**

```
Monster::Monster(){
    m_state = new Frog();
}

void Monster::kiss(){
    delete m_state;
    m_state = new Prince();
}

void Monster::welcome(){
    m_state->welcome();
}

void Monster::sayGoodbye(){
    m_state->sayGoodbye();
}

Monster::~Monster(){
    delete m_state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in c++ structs are public by default and class and private by default therefore m_state is private (objects defined in class are private except if another protection statement has been made)

```
class Monster{
    State* m_state;
public:
    Monster();
    void kiss();
    void welcome();
    void sayGoodbye();
    ~Monster();
};
```

is the same as

```
class Monster{
private:
    State* m_state;
public:
    Monster();
    void kiss();
    void welcome();
    void sayGoodbye();
    ~Monster();
};
```

whereas

```
 struct Monster{
        State* m_state;
    public:
        Monster();
        void kiss();
        void welcome();
        void sayGoodbye();
        ~Monster();
    };
```

in this struct m_state is public

Comment: And what if there _are_ some attributes defined in Private but `m_state` is still in Default? Is it just his way of coding?

Comment: If there is no protection statement inside the class, the protection is default. In classes, the default protection is private. Therefore even if there is another private section inside the class, as long as m_state is not defined after public (or protected) statement, it will be private.